# Special Relativity-Book

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, book-recommendation

I would a good book to study the Special Relativity. In my course the professor has treated the following topics:

$(1)$ Lagrangian and hamiltonian dynamic of a charged particle;

$(2)$ Relaticistic cinematic;

$(3)$ Conservation principles in particle collisions.

In particoular I need a book full of exercises.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it math or physics that you seek?

Comment: Maybe a good start is http://www.phas.ubc.ca/~mcmillan/rqpdfs/1_relativity.pdf

Comment: There is another one with a lot of problems http://www.amazon.com/Problem-Book-Relativity-Gravitation-Lightman/dp/069108162X?ie=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00

Comment: FYI, the gold-standard from my student days in the 1970s was [**Spacetime Physics**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0716723271) by Taylor and Wheeler (yes, THAT "Wheeler"). However, the focus is more on basic physical principles, and the exposition is at a mathematical level that is far below what "Lagrangian" and "Hamiltonian" in your question suggests you're looking for.

Comment: I looked through my books at home this weekend, and two more books that were fairly well known in the 1970s are **Essential Relativity** by Wolfgang Rindler and **Relativity for Scientists and Engineers** by Ray Skinner (a Dover edition of Skinner's book came out in 1982).

Answer (score 0):

I really like [Gravity: An Introduction to Einstein's General Relativity](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805386629) by Hartle. It covers special relativity in the first few chapters. It also somehow manages to cover general relativity by holding your hand through differential geometry.

Answer (score 0):

I really enjoyed reading S. Adams' book *[Relativity: an introduction to spacetime physics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0748406212)*. It is easy to read, and it is written mathematically (for instance viewing Lorentz transformation as a rotation etc.).